# Vertically centering a glyphicon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I vertically center the `glyphicon` (and `badge`) elements in this context:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        Multi-line content...
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"/>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        Multi-line content...
        <span class="badge">123</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

By multi-line content I mean a varying number of lines and in some cases wrapping text and a variety of font sizes.

This is to provide navigation pages for a mobile app that include the visual hint of an arrow over to the right. When the content wraps or has other multi-line elements vertical centering is what other frameworks provide but they typically use background images. I am using Bootstrap 3.0.0.

Answer (score 4):

How about this..

```
.list-group-item span {
 margin-top: -0.5em;
}
```

DEMO: http://bootply.com/95790

Comment: I should have been clearer. By multi-line I meant an unknown number of lines and various font sizes so fixed offsets won't do it. I'll improve the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="list-group">
  <div class="list-group-item">
    <div class="media-body">
      Multi-line content...
    </div>
    <div class="media-right" style="vertical-align:middle;">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should explain why this is a solution to the question asked.